# How to do configuation management in my PHP third-party?

Tags: php, service, configuration

I have, let's say, five types of job A,B,C,D,E. Each has different configuration. I want to make a configuration system in PHP, which is solely in PHP. In this system I like to return an object of configuration on specifying job type:

```
$obj=new ServiceConfiguration(); $configForA= $obj->getConfig('A');
```

`getConfig` reads the config, which may contain URL, job server, port and set this in config object. In writing all this I want that proper design should be followed.

Should I write all config parameter in a PHP array in a config file or there is any better alternative to it? Can I use external parties like YAML to store config? I want to know the best way to achieve it. Please answer with the whole design.

NOTE: I want to write a third party which should be written in PHP and should have no or minimal dependency on external third parties like YAML.

Comment: Factory Pattern https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method/php/1

Comment: "Please answer with whole design" - I think this is going to be rather broad for Stack Overflow. Can you show us what you have already, and explain what problem in particular you are foreseeing?

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly use JSON files for configuration and a PHP class to read thoses files.

Accessing a var is doing by giving a string with underscores, that way I can explore the depth of the JSON file

example :

database.json

```
{
    "prod" : 
    {
        "server" : "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "key_with_underscore" : "value"
}
```

script.php

```
Config::get('database_prod_server');
Config::get('database_key_with_underscore');
```

I also do some small treatment to access JSON array as PHP array but basically, that's it.

In fact the config class just transform a multidimensionnal array to one-dimensionnal array by flattening it and insert an underscore for each new "dimension", then I stock the result in a variable (and cache it).